# Find vertical asymptotes of function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have problem solve this task.

Find vertical asymptotes of this function:

$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2x+1}$$

I found the domain:$$D\in(-\infty,2]\cup[2,+\infty)$$

I solved limes:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to-2^{-}}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2x+1}=0$$
and
$$\lim\limits_{x\to2^{+}}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2x+1}=0$$

And I concluded that there are no vertical asymptotes?
Is that right?

Comment: The domain you found is wrong. First of all you need $x^2-4 \ge 0$, or $x \in (-\infty,-2]\cup[2,\infty)$, note that this isn't exactly what you've arrived at because of the $-2$ instead of the $2$; but you also need the denominator to not equal $0$, so $2x+1 \ne 0$, a.k.a. $x \ne -\frac{1}{2}$. Now you'll likely find a vertical asymptote at $x = -\frac{1}{2}$. (This also changes the domain, $-\frac{1}{2}$ also has to be excluded.)

Comment: Vertical asymptotes typically occur where the denominator of a function equals 0.  The denominator, $2x+1=0$ when $x=\frac{1}{2}$ which is not within the domain of the function.  Therefore, I agree with your conclusion, but do not agree with your logic behind that conclusion.

Comment: So the domain is:$D\in (-\infty,-2]\cup[2,\infty)/\{-\frac{1}{2}\}$ So for vertical asymptotes I have to find limes tending to $-\frac{1}{2}$ on the left and right?

Answer (score 1):

To find the largest possible domain, we want $x^2-4 \ge 0$ and $2x+1 \ne 0$, which corresponds to $$((-\infty, -2] \cup [2, \infty))-\{-\frac12\}=(-\infty, -2] \cup [2, \infty).$$

The function does not have a denominator that can take value $0$, there is no vertical asymptote. I have attached a plot of the function.

[image]